# SetState to push new data to the state array object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to do a POST to an API endpoint, there's a field called space_photos, it accept array of objects.

this is my callback func whenever user uploaded a photo.

```
constructor(){
this.space_photo_holder = [];
}

callback = (e) => {

    this.space_photos_holder.push(e);

    this.setState({space_photos: this.space_photos_holder})

}
```

I think the code is legit but is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `concat` instead of push. It returns a updated array

```
constructor(){
    this.state = {
      space_photos= []
    }
}

callback = (e) => {

    this.setState({space_photos: this.state.space_photos.concat(e)})

}
```

Comment: just tried this and this won't work, the array will always be one. I want to push array not replace them.

Comment: You are right that wouldnt have worked since you were not changing the space_photos_holder array. Use the updated approach

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use spread operator. It's recommended to set initial state in `constructor` and use the functional version of `setState` when the new state is based on the previous state.

```
constructor(){
  this.state = { space_photos: [] };
}

callback = (e) => {
  this.setState((state) => { space_photos : [...state.space_photos, ...e]})
}
```

Also, you can use `cancat` method.

```
callback = (e) => {
  this.setState((state) => { space_photos : state.space_photos.cancat([e]) });
}
```

Comment: concat is cleaner.